# Octave - strcat() not trimming trailing whitespace when called with a single argument

Tags: matlab, octave

Why does `strcat()` with only a single argument fail to trim trailing whitespace?

I am trying to use strcat() to trim trailing whitespace from a character array:

```
s = "cheese   ";
s = strcat(s);
```

but this returns `s = "cheese   "`, i.e. no change in the whitespace. If I add a second argument to strcat(), such as `s = strcat(s, "");` now `s = "cheese"`.

I'm doing it this way, rather than calling strtrim(), because this is explicitly how the zyBooks textbook wants us to accomplish this task for a single string -- their examples show strcat() being used in this manner. What am I overlooking?

Comment: It looks like it's the expected behaviour [as staded in the reference](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/strcat.html). I wonder why it's bad to use `strtrim(s)` as the function is made for that.

Comment: I'm not sure about the latter; they don't mention it at all. As to the former, where does it state that trailing whitespace for a single cell string is preserved? Is it implied by "Trailing white space for any character string input is eliminated before the strings are concatenated"?

Comment: `strcat` behaves  differently in Matlab and in Octave. `strcat` purpose is concatenation (not trimming).

Comment: @apraetor In the link I posted above, it's says : "_Note that cell string values do **not** have whitespace trimmed_". Maybe I have a problem with English there or with octave vocabulary, but I understand the documentation as followed : if `strcat` is given cell string**s** as input it will behave as you expect but if you give it a single cell string, it won't trim the spaces.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the actual question? There doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte "cell string values" is plural, but I take your meaning; it is one of those cases where English is ambiguous. If the examples had included a single-argument case it would have been much more clear.

Comment: Bugreport https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?49094

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does remove trailing whitespace in Matlab, but not in Octave. This happens sometimes: Octave's functions work more or less like Matlab's, but with some differences. Sometimes these differences are untentional, sometimes they are not.

In this case I think the behaviour you encountered is a bug in the Octave function, because its [documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/strcat.html) says

> Trailing white space for any character string input is eliminated before the strings are concatenated.

which is not what it's doing when there is a single string as input.

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection (and the clarity of hindsight), I think the author of the documentation knew what they meant, but didn't make it clear: they wrote "strcat(s1, s2, ...)" where in the Matlab docs it is shown as "strcat(s1, ...)". Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If you can confirm that `strcat ('foo    ')` returns `'foo'` in matlab, you should file a bugreport on savannah http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave Please use Item Group "Matlab compatibility". Thank you

Comment: @Andy Yes, I can confirm that (tested on Matlab R2015b). apraetor, can you file the bugreport (if you see it fit)?

Comment: Man you guys move fast, I went to bed and woke up to all this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This Bug was reported on savannah](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?49094) and [fixed on the default branch](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/d7931cb69486) some hours later.

You can wait for the next release which includes this change or just download [strcat.m from the mercurial repo](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/raw-file/d7931cb69486/scripts/strings/strcat.m) and replace strcat.m in your Octave installation.

Comment: Aww my first genuine bug! Now I wish I hadn't jumped the gun on answers! (that link to the default branch doesn't work for me)

Comment: Looks like the gnu server (http://hg.sv.gnu.org/hgweb/) currently has some problems... Try again in some hours